# React Native Animated setValue() problem?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

Actually I'm trying to set value of the animation with **setValue()** after **Animated.timing()** is finished and want to use this updated animated value then in a loop animation.

```
//Initialising animation value=50
const leftAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(50)).current 
useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(leftAnim,{
        toValue:360,
        duration:3000,
        easing:Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver:false,
    }).start(({finished}) => {
        //Updating animation value=100
        leftAnim.setValue(100)
        //Animated API is not considering the setValue and starting the loop animation with the first value i.e 50 instead of 100
        Animated.loop(
            Animated.timing(leftAnim,{
                toValue:360,
                duration:5000,
                easing:Easing.linear,
                useNativeDriver:false
            })
        ).start()
    })
},[])
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: what all solutions you have tried yet?

Comment: @sidverma I guess we cannot modify the initial value for animation and run animation with the same final value(toValue) and duration but different start property in Animated.timing. I'm trying to create a new animation for each state of the application.

Comment: I have added one example here, can you think through this code and map your scenario : https://snack.expo.dev/NBpVpcLKI

Comment: @sidverma Thank you for your quick reply. Actually, my case is a little intricate. I need to change the start animation property. So suppose if my animation starts with 5 and ends at 10 with a duration of 100, then I need to change the starting value to 0 and duration to 200 leaving the final value as it is. Here final value is left position CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `leftAnim.setOffset(nextStart)` and inside loop adjust end accordingly.
[Demo on snack expo](https://snack.expo.dev/uyR0BtK0M)

```js
import React, { Component, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Easing, StyleSheet, View, Animated, Button, Text } from 'react-native';

const start = 0;
const end = 100;

export default Anim = () => {
  const leftAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(start)).current;
  const [curValue, setCurValue] = useState(start);

  useEffect(() => {
    leftAnim.addListener((v) => {
      setCurValue(v.value.toFixed(0));
    });

    Animated.timing(leftAnim, {
      toValue: end,
      duration: 5000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start(({ finished }) => {
      //setting value to 80
      leftAnim.setOffset(80);

      // increment only by 20, 80 + 20 = 100
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.timing(leftAnim, {
          toValue: end - 80,
          duration: 2000,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        })
      ).start();
    });
  }, [leftAnim]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.Image
        source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')}
        style={{ width: 40, height: 40, transform: [{ translateY: leftAnim }] }}
      />

      <Text>Current Value: {curValue}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  input: {
    height: 50,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#ededed',
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 9,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did it but in a different way. Although this method can also be used in this scenario. But my use case is different. I need to play the animation in the loop and then stop and restart it multiple times. How you will achieve this if you want to stop and reset and restart the animation multiple times on a button click with the same code?

Comment: One more thing how about putting Animated.timing() in a function expression and then calling it in the loop from Animated.start(callback). That way we don't require setting up of offset value and can use the setValue() method inside .start(callback).   This is how I did it :)

Comment: Looks like the value is being cloned or cached in some sort of closure. And using function expression is provides the loop current value.

Comment: Yes, that might be the case. Well, I did somehow. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Repalce this:
`leftAnim.setValue(100)`

With this:
`leftAnim._startingValue = 100`

Now, when the loop animation starts, it will start from `100` because we've changed the starting value.

[Snack Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@tayyabreact/so_71148703)